# How to make textfield with ['#ajax']['keypressed'] = TRUE trigger only on click and not on blur?

Tags: ajax

When I specify `['#ajax']['keypressed'] = TRUE` for textfield, trigger runs not only when I click `ENTER` (as it is mentioned in documentation), but also when textfield loses focus (must be `blur` event in JavaScript). So how can I avoid this?

Comment: The official documentation is here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/ajax/8.2.x

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late but for the others :

```
['#ajax']['event'] = 'none'
```